# Escaping association name in grails criteria to not conflict with containing class variable name

Tags: grails, escaping, associations, criteria, conflict

This is the simplified version of my grails domain class:

```
class Car {
  int year
  Model model

  List<Car> findCarsBySomeCriteria(int modelId) {
     BuildableCriteria c = createCriteria()
     List<Car> carList = (List<Car>) c.list {
        'in'("year", [1998, 1999])
        model {
            eq("id", modelId)
        }
     }

     carList
  }
}
```

Turns out that this criteria query fails as the `model` association mentioned in the query conflicts with the `model` property of the class.

Is there any way to escape the `model` in criteria query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `createAlias`, like

```
List<Car> carList = (List<Car>) c.list {
    'in'("year", [1998, 1999])
    createAlias('model', 'mdl')
    eq("mdl.id", modelId)
}
```